# How to resolve module not found error in webpack/reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have created a reactjs/webpack app with an component created in main.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import cube  from 'my-module';

class MainLayout extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('testing=main constructor')

        console.log(cube(3));

    }


    render() {
        console.log('main render' )
        return (
            <div>hello</div>
        );
    }
}

export default MainLayout
```

I am trying to get my head around import and export in es6 and created a module in the same directory:

```
// module "my-module.js"
export default function cube(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}
```

However I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./app/components/layouts/main/main.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'my-module' in ...
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't specify a path (starting with `./`) before the name of your module, webpack (using regular nodejs module resolution) will look for `my-module` in the nearest `node_modules` folder.

So if the file that contains your `MainLayout` class is in the same folder as the `my-module.js` then your import statement would look like:

```
import cube from './my-module'
```

If it was one level above it would look like:

```
import cube from '../my-module'
```

Then one above that:

```
import cube from '../../my-module'
```

and so forth.

It's possible to configure webpack with aliases or have it know about specific files that act like top-level modules. Another technique which I've found very useful is to structure your app like:

```
node_modules/
src/
  node_modules/
    app.js
    my-module.js

webpack.config.js
```

That way you can always look for any of your own modules without specifying a path since node will first look in your `src/node_modules` folder, then if it can't find it there, will look in your top level `node_modules` folder where all your npm packages live. If you do this though, make sure not to put `src/node_modules` in `.gitignore`!